# don't load pvr.ccz cocos2d-x for wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

my version : cocos2dx-0.13.0-wp8-0.8
my code is:

```
CCTexture2D::PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha(true); 
    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Towers/TArrow-hd.plist", "Towers/TArrow-hd.pvr.ccz");
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()- >spriteFrameByName("Arrow-13.png");
CCSprite *sp = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(frame); 
sp->setPosition(ccp(100,100)); 
this->addChild(sp, 1);
```

run to "CCSprite *sp = CCSprite::spriteWithSpriteFrame(frame)", have exception,
spriteWithSpriteFrameName("") also

exception:

```
D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
```

The thread 0xba4 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x00B987E0, Refcount: 6. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
The thread 0x668 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The thread 0x20 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00B9A530, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x02CC17F8, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]

Answer (score 0):

change pvr.ccz to png, it's ok